# Ruby on Rails -- Can I change upload tmpdir on each user sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, file-upload, tmp

I want to change tmpdir of fileupload on each user sessions with Rubu on Rails.

For example:

UserA's upload tmpdir
/home/userA/tmp

UserB's upload tmpdir
/home/userB/tmp

Is it possible to do it on Ruby On Rails?

Comment: I found perser.rb has a code to create Tempfile when uploading.

body = Tempfile.new("RackMultipart")

but How can I tell him a new tmpdir?

Comment: I found a solution myself.

override get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body
method and post 'tmpdir' values when POST files.

`pm = @params.to_params_hash`
`body = Tempfile.new("RackMultipart", pm['tmpdir'])`